# how to ensure that a page's native javascript is generated from a trusted source?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For security reasons, I need to run native javascript code through a trusted source. Could someone tell me how I can generate a native JavaScript library to run code through it instead of the one generated by default by the page?

there's a way that a user suggested loading an `<iframe>` element into the page which also generates a new `window` element and `document` and then through `.contentWindow` and `.contentDocument` solves the problem, but it's still not secure because it uses the `window` and `document` objects loaded in the parent element.

Another way I've apparently found it is using the `WebAssembly JavaScript API`, but I still haven't figured out how to import the latest version through it.

Could someone help me generate a Native JavaScript Library in the best way possible?

Provisory solution found:

```
window.console.log = maliciousCode;

console.log("it's not a secure Native JavaScript");

const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

iframe.contentWindow.console.log("it's more safe but still isn't a secure Native JavaScript");
```

Comment: What is _"the javascript native code"_?

Comment: @jabaa I added an example of a alternative solution that I found so they can understand what I need approximately.

Comment: @jabaa I don't know how to simplify it anymore. I just need to ensure that loading the ``window`` and ``document`` elements (in this case native javascript) are from a trusted source (in this case mine or the browser)

Comment: What it's not clear is what security problem you are trying to prevent, like... where's that `maliciousCode` variable comming from? why is it malicious?. It's also not clear what you mean by `Native` JavaScript either.

Comment: @arieljuod The subject is similar to this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27903655/is-it-safe-to-rely-on-global-native-objects-in-javascript-particularly-the-obje

Comment: If you are worried about 3rd-party code changing the base objects JavaScript uses (like Object, Window, etc), I think you are better checking the Content-Security-Policy meta tag to only ever allow content from sources you decide are safe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy. Then you can be sure any JS run is something you allowed, the browser will enforce that.